# How should I tune Postgresql for 20 GB of RAM?

Tags: performance, postgresql, memory

I've been fortunate enough to have the use of a 20GB Linode instance running Ubuntu 64 bit. I want to try to optimize PostGres for this service, but I don't know what I should prioritize changing.

I have several datasets of 20,000 or so rows and the calculations that are being performed are memory intensive queries (spatial analyses) with a small number of rows being written after each request. The total number of users is very small (10 - 50).

I've read through this [article](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) on the Postgresql site but I don't know enough about how this works, to know what I should prioritize. I've also looked at [advice](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/tuning.html) on what to change for geo type work here.

For example, I tried changing the `shared_buffers` to `200MB` (which is much less than 75% of 20GB). This resulted in the following error message:

> - Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
>
>   - The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: 2013-03-10 12:21:58 EDT FATAL:  could not create shared memory
>       segment: Invalid argument 2013-03-10 12:21:58 EDT DETAIL:  Failed
>       system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=47742976, 03600). 2013-03-10
>       12:21:58 EDT HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request
>       for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMMAX parameter. 
>       You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with
>       larger SHMMAX.  To reduce the request size (currently 47742976 bytes),
>       reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing
>       shared_buffers or max_connections.    If the request size is already
>       small, it's possible that it is less than your kernel's SHMMIN
>       parameter, in which case raising the request size or reconfiguring
>       SHMMIN is called for.     The PostgreSQL documentation contains more
>       information about shared memory configuration.

I returned this to it's original value and tried changing:

```
work_mem = 50MB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
```

My problem is that I don't know which values I should try changing, or how I should prioritize which values are key to experiment with and test. What should I specifically do to optimize this database?

Comment: In most cases, setting effective_cache_size to 20GB, and shared_buffers to xx MB will suffice.

Comment: The error message you quoted in full (thankyou) refers to the operating system settings you must change in order to increase `shared_buffers`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC

Comment: As for figuring out what you need to do, that depends on all sorts of factors. Your workload - read or write heavy? Lots of small queries  or fewer big queries? Client count? Using connection pooling? Many short transactions or fewer longer ones? How big is the database on disk and how much of it is "hot" ie actively and regularly queried? What's the performance of the associated storage system like?

Comment: @CraigRinger I do mention several of these measures in the question - I'm not very familiar with how to measure or categorize client pooling. What do you mean by associated storage system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend using [`pgtune`](https://github.com/gregs1104/pgtune#readme) written by Greg Smith.

Simply run it on your server as follows:

```
pgtune -i postgresql.conf -o postgresql-tuned.conf
```

It has few more options, but just doing that and using generated `postgresql.conf` will do wonders for your server performance.

I think PostgreSQL should include this in standard install, and even run it by default - such that people cannot complain about bad PostgreSQL performance.

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I need. I'd stumbled towards some of the settings but was not familiar with all the things that I should change.

Comment: +1 Useful tool. Didn't get updated much since Postgres 8.4. But mostly still works for the latest version 9.2.

Comment: Once I fixed the `SHMMAX` problem (solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/44373/how-to-fix-postgresql-installation ) `pgtune` worked like a charm.

Comment: Uh, I did not realize you had shmmax issue until I reread your question again! of course you need to tweak sysctl.conf. BTW, in PostgreSQL 9.3 this will not be necessary

Comment: @A-B-B: nobody is forcing you to use it. But, it continues to work just fine on Postgres 9.3 and it does help, tremendously.

Comment: @mvp, `pgtune` helps over the defaults, but I wouldn't call it "fine". One can do better at args such as `default_statistics_target`, `wal_buffers`, `checkpoint_completion_target`, `checkpoint_timeout`, etc. I have some working [notes](https://www.evernote.com/l/AWzxff1rUXdFQpv0GGoJTSr3cmweBO3NPaY).

Comment: @A-B-B: of course, nothing can beat knowledgeable DBA. My whole point was that it would be nice if pgtune was shipped in default distribution and was used to create default postgresql.conf - it would stop 99% user complaints of "why Postgres is so slow after I installed and run it".

Comment: @mvp, it should be `initdb`'s job to tune it right from the start. Having `pgtune` included for later tuning will also help, but only if it's maintained, of course, as it should be.

Comment: @A-B-B: exactly. yes, it certainly should be maintained as part of main distribution. Perhaps pginit should use some of pgtune logic as some library or just call its executable (which probably means that pgtune should we rewritten from Python to C)

Comment: @mvp, [here](https://github.com/impredicative/pgtune) is a tuner I wrote.

Comment: Base `pg_tune` hasn't been updated in a year, but there are some [more recent forks](https://github.com/gregs1104/pgtune/pulls)

Comment: As mentioned, the CLI tool hasn't been updated for a while, **but there's an online version that is up-to-date, even for PG 13**: https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua

Answer (score 5):

You will need to increase the shmmax, shmall, msgmax and msgmnb settings on your server.  PGTUNE, as mentioned in the other answer, should tell you what to set them to.

You can do that like this:

```
sysctl -w kernel.shmmax={{value}}
sysctl -w kernel.shmall={{value}}
sysctl -w kernel.msgmax={{value}}
sysctl -w kernel.msgmnb={{value}}
```

You can check what the values already are like this:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmall
cat /proc/sys/kernel/msgmax
cat /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb
```

Comment: As a word of caution, users must remember to always first check the existing value before updating it. If the existing value is already higher, and it may very well be, it then doesn't need to be updated.